# Is it possible to copy a gradle wrapper with a gradle task?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

i am developing spring boot microservices. 
Then I generated a service-template and added a gradle wrapper. 
Then I have a seperate bootstrap project with a gradle task wo copy the template to a generate a new project.
But if I copy the template, there appear errors with the gradle wrapper. 
`could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`

I think it's because I rename the project from "template" to "xyz"

This is the directory content after I copied it:
.gitignore
.gradle
README.md
build.gradle
gradle
gradle.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
src
My gradle task to copy the template:

```
task create(type: Copy) {

  def parentFolder = "../"
  def templateFolder = new File("$parentFolder/fmp-template")

  def serviceName = project.hasProperty('sn') ? "${sn}" : "dummy"
  def fmpServiceName = "fmp-${sn}"

  def newServiceFolder = new File("$parentFolder/${fmpServiceName}")

  def serviceNameReplaced = ""
  if ("${serviceName}".contains('-')) {
    serviceNameReplaced = "${serviceName}".replaceAll('-','')
  }
  else {
    serviceNameReplaced = serviceName
  }

  def servicePort = project.hasProperty('sp') ? sp : '9999'
  def maintainerName = "${defaultMaintainerName1}${defaultMaintainerName2}"
  def maintainerMail = "${defaultMaintainerMail}"
  maintainerName = getMaintainerName()
  maintainerMail = getMaintainerMail()

  // replace tokens in files
  filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
      'serviceName'           : serviceName.toString(),
      'serviceNameReplaced'   : serviceNameReplaced.toString(),
      'servicePort'           : servicePort.toString(),
      'maintainerName'        : maintainerName,
      'maintainerMail'        : maintainerMail,
  ]

  // copy template to new service
  from templateFolder
  into newServiceFolder

  // workaround because Copy Task is excluding some files
  doFirst {
    DirectoryScanner.defaultExcludes.each { DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude it }
  }

  doLast {
    DirectoryScanner.resetDefaultExcludes()
    renameFolder("$parentFolder/${fmpServiceName}/src/main/java/de/microservices/fmp/@serviceNameReplaced@",
             "$parentFolder/${fmpServiceName}/src/main/java/de/microservices/fmp/${serviceNameReplaced}")
     renameFolder("$parentFolder/${fmpServiceName}/src/test/java/de/microservices/fmp/@serviceNameReplaced@",
             "$parentFolder/${fmpServiceName}/src/test/java/de/microservices/fmp/${serviceNameReplaced}")
    commandGitInit(newServiceFolder)
  }
}
```

My Question: 
Is it possible to copy a gradle wrapper with a gradle task - and how? 

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: sorry - I added the error

Comment: See my edit....

Answer (score 0):

Also copy the `gradle` directory, not only the `gradlew` scripts.

**Edit**:
After seeing your edit, I don't think it makes any sense for you to copy the wrapper, since in order to do that, you're using a Gradle task, which requires a local Gradle installation. Simply generate the wrapper by running `gradle wrapper`.

Tip: Next time you post a question, don't hold back useful information.

Comment: i also copied the `.gradle` directory.

Comment: @m1well Pardon me if I don't believe you. Post a reproducible project.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that I copy it with a gradle task, not with the bash `cp` command.

Comment: @m1well You wrote a Gradle task to copy the Gradle wrapper? You must be paid by the hour :) Like I said, if you copied the directory with the executables, it works. If you claim it doesn't, show us. If you can't ,accept the answer.

Comment: haha - nice humor :) now I didn't write a task for copying a gradle wrapper. i wrote a task to copy my microservice template (with some spring boot sources) and all work but the gradle wrapper exits with an error (see above).

Comment: @m1well - Initial triage of this is pretty straightforward - does your `.gradle` directory contain all of the files that you expect it to contain?

Comment: yes It does - i know now the problem: copying the sources with gradle copy task corrupts the `gradle-wrapper.jar` - if i check the jar with `jar tvf gradle-wrapper.jar` there appears an error: `java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file` - so it is a problem with the gradle copy task - but I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

sorry first for "wrong" question. but I thought this is a known behavior and someone has a solution. 
again the problem in fact: the copy task in gradle has a problem with copying "zip/jar - files" 
after a long research I have a solution now: 
1. I excluded the jar file in the main copy task 
2. I created a new copy task where I only copy the jar file

```
task copyGradleWrapper(type: Copy) {
  // copy gradle wrapper separately because of "unzipping problems"
  def templateWrapper = new File("../fmp-template/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar")
  def newServiceWrapper = new File("${newServiceFolder}/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar")
  from zipTree(templateWrapper)
  into newServiceWrapper
}
```

hopefully my solution answer is better than my question ;)